# On the reflection of a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, wienerprocess

Let ${(I_t)}_{t\geq 0}$ be a stochastic integral defined by
$$
I_t=\int_{0}^{t}\theta_sdW_t, 
$$
where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},{(\mathcal{F}_t)}_{t\geq 0},\mathbb{P})$ and $\theta$ a stochastic process adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$ satisfying the follows condition of integrability
$$
E\left(\int_{0}^{t}\theta_s^2 ds\right)<\infty\;\;\  \forall t> 0.
$$

We define the first passage time at $a$ for Brownian motion $W$ by the following random variable
$$
\tau_a = \inf\{t\geq 0,W_t\geq a\},
$$
where $a>0$.

It is possible to show that $\tau_a$ is a stopping time. Moreover, By virtue of the reflection principle, we know that the following process

\begin{equation*}
Z_t =
\begin{cases}
W_t     \qquad & if \qquad 0 \leq t \leq \tau_a \\
2a-W_t           \qquad & if \qquad   t > \tau_a
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

also follows a standard Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P}$.

My question is as follows :
Is it possible to rewrite the process $I$ in relation to the process $Z$?

I would like your opinion on this issue, thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean in relation ?

Comment: I want to write the stochastic integral with respect to Brownian motion $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Set
$$X_t=\exp\left(-\int_{0}^{t}\theta_sdW_s^{\mathbb{P}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\theta_s^{\,2}ds\right)$$
By application of Gisanov theorem , we have

- $X_t$ is a $\mathbb{P}-$ martingale.
- By changing the measure $\mathbb{P}$ to  $\mathbb{Q}$ such that
  $$\mathbb{E^P}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big{|}\mathcal{F_t}\right]=\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big{|}_\mathcal{F_t}=X_t$$
  then

  $$W_t^{\mathbb{Q}}=W_t^{\mathbb{P}}+I_t$$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ standard wiener process.
  We have
  \begin{equation*}
  Z_t =
  \begin{cases}
  W_t^{\mathbb{Q}}-I_t     \qquad & , \qquad 0 \leq t \leq \tau_a \\
  2a-W_t^{\mathbb{Q}}+I_t           \qquad & , \qquad   t > \tau_a
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation*}
  then (If  I am right)
  \begin{equation*}
  dZ_t =
  \begin{cases}
  dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}}-dI_t     \qquad & , \qquad 0 \leq t \leq \tau_a \\
  -dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}}+dI_t           \qquad & , \qquad   t > \tau_a
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation*}